# Integer interpreted as date when added to Google Sheets by R + googlesheets

Tags: r, google-sheets-api, r-googlesheets

I am trying to add pairs of values (date, value) to Google Sheets via `gs_add_row` from googlesheets. This succeeds, except that both values show up as dates on Google Sheets.

I checked the "value" beforehand to make sure it is as expected (eg. 50), but Sheets displays a date (1970-02-20).

I even tried setting the cell formatting in Sheets to "Numbers" instead of "Automatic" but it made no difference.

Is there a way to specify variable types?

**EDIT**
Example code:

```
library(lubridate)
library(googlesheets)
library(dplyr)

#URL <- "[some 'published to the web' Google Sheet URL]"
dt <- ymd(today())
val <- 50

URL %>% 
    gs_url() %>% 
    gs_add_row(ws=3, input = c(dt, val))
```

Comment: You really need to show a snippet of the data before it got exported to google sheets (`dput(head(yourdf,20))`). Check the structure of the data by using `str` to make sure that your column is actually is not `Date`.

Comment: @Abdou It's not even a data frame; just a vector of a date and value pair. I checked that the values are correct in the code right before `gs_add_row` tries to add them to Google Sheets.

Comment: when you use `c`, the output type is determined from the highest type of the components in the hierarchy `NULL < raw < logical < integer < double < complex < character < list < expression`. Therefore, the output of the concatenation (using `c`) is of `Date` class. If you had done `c(val, dt)`, the output type would be `numeric`. Your best bet is to do: `gs_add_row(ws=3, input = c(as.character(dt),val)))`. Try it and let me know.

Comment: @Abdou `as.character(dt)` got the same result as before. And for fun I also tried `input = c(val, dt)` and both are still dates again!

Comment: Are you sure? Cause I just tried it and it worked for me. Again, the code is:
```URL %>%
    gs_url() %>% 
    gs_add_row(ws=3, input = c(as.character(dt), val))```

Comment: I got `2016-07-05 50`

Comment: Make sure to use the `as.character` transformation within your `gs_add_row` call.

Comment: @Abdou I now tried it on a new Sheet and it works as you said: `2016-07-05 50`. I tried again on the old Sheet and it continued to fail! I copied the data, deleted the old Sheet, and made a new Sheet with the same data, and now adding works. Thank you!!

Comment: Oh great! Glad it finally worked. I will add the comments as the answer for you to accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue arises from the usage of `c` to concatenate `dt` and `val` into a vector.
when you use `c`, the output type is determined from the highest type of the components in the hierarchy `NULL < raw < logical < integer < double < complex < character < list < expression`. Therefore, the output of the concatenation (using `c`) is of `Date` class in this case.
If you had done `c(val, dt)`, the output type would be `numeric`.

Your best bet is to do:

```
URL %>%
    gs_url() %>% 
    gs_add_row(ws=3, input = c(as.character(dt), val))
```

If this does not work the first time around, you may have to delete the old Sheet, make a new Sheet with the same data, and run the code on the new sheet.

Thanks!